# Magento : How to hide the default Store View code from the url

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

The site has 2 languages: English and French, represented by 2 store views.  French is the default one.  For our SEO efforts we need to have the following urls:

1. French - http://www.domain.com/category/product
2. English - http://www.domain.com/en/category/product

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Add Store Codes to URL is the all or nothing setting.  We just need to turn it off for the default store only.
I’ve done a lot of searching through the forums and wiki but there’s nothing on the subject.

Please any sugestions?

Comment: I don't think there is a way without some custom coding. Per chance it could be done with small effort and xml routing settings, but I haven't digged through that yet.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you:

[store-code-in-url-for-every-store-view-except-for-default][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/store-code-in-url-for-every-store-view-except-for-default

Comment: i have tested it but no result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finnaly i solved this magic probleme , i hope that's save others persone  here is the details :

1- Download the zip existe in this page  :  https://github.com/Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes

2- unzip the file and put the folder called  "Knectar" in {app/code/community/} and Knectar_Storecodes.xml file in {app/etc/modules}

3- In your backoffice go to "System > Tools > Compilation" and click the rebuild button

4- always in backoffice  got to "System > Configuration > Web > URL options" and set the attribute  "and default store view" to No and save the configuration

5- Clear your cach magento  and enjoy your application :) .

Comment: Thanks for finding this solution. Was looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I have developed an extension for that.

[image]

It is available on GitHub: https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a quick solution to your problem, but I see that's possible through 2 steps :

1 / Using the advise commented by @user3154108 and trying this tip https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/store-code-in-url-for-every-store-view-except-for-default
2 / For SEO SITEMAP, it's possible to override the following file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php
public function generateXml()
{
    ...
}
```

and replace the default store code by NULL.
For more details try to look at this post : http://alanstorm.com/generating_google_sitemaps_in_magento

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I had already selected to not show store code in url in the config.  I also didn't want to install an extension just to handle something this minor.  Here's my EASY solution:

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Widget/Link.php`

Search for (line 91 in Magento 1.7.x / line 100 in Magento 1.9.x)

> $this->_href = $this->_href . $symbol . "___store=" . $store->getCode();

And modify to

> $this->_href = $this->_href;

Upload and save your changes and you'll now not have your widget (dynamically) inserted links getting appended with ?___store=default.

Credit: [DesignHaven](https://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/10/force-removal-of-store-code-default-from-urls-in-magento/)

Answer (score -1):

Under System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options you 
change "Add Store Code to Urls" to "NO" as on the attached screenshot
[image]